# php validate string with preg_match

Tags: php, string, validation, preg-match

I am trying to verify in PHP with preg_match that an input string contains only "a-z, A-Z, -, _ ,0-9" characters. If it contains just these, then validate.

I tried to search on google but I could not find anything usefull.

Can anybody help?

Thank you !

Comment: Which loser down-voted my question ?

Answer (score 4):

Use the pattern `'/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$/'`, if an empty string is also valid.  Otherwise `'/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$/'`

So:

```
$yourString = "blahblah";
if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$/', $yourString)) {
    #your string is good
}
```

Also, note that you want to put a '-' last in the character class as part of the character class, that way it is read as a literal '-' and not the dash between two characters such as the hyphen between A-Z.

Comment: What happens if "preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$/', $yourString" returns 0, as in it doesnt match ? You still validate it, right ?

Comment: Good clarification.  I edited the example.  This way if preg_match is anything but 0 or FALSE, you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = 'abc123-_';
echo preg_match('/^[\w|\-]+$/', $data); //match and output 1

$data = 'abc..';
echo preg_match('/^[\w|\-]+$/', $data); //not match and output 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject):

```
if (preg_replace('/[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]/', '', $string)) {
  echo "Detect non valid character inside the string";
}
```

The idea is to remove any valid chars, if the result is NOT empty do the code.