# How do I search if a string contains at least one word from a list using regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string and need to check if any of the words in my list are in the string. 
My list looks like this:

```
$keywords = array(
    "l.*ion",
    "test",
    'one',
    'two',
    'three'
);
```

1. If I have string `This is my lion` then I need to return `true`.
2. If I have string `This is my lotion` then I need to return `true`.
3. If I have string `This is my dandelion` then return `false`.
4. If I have string `This is my location` then return `true`.
5. If I have string `This is my test` then return `true`.
6. If I have string `This is my testing` then return `false`.

This is my code:

```
$keywords = implode($keywords,"|");
$list= "/\b$keywords\b/i";
$my_string= "This is my testing";
preg_match($list, $my_string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo $matches[0][1];
```

But when I do `This is my testing` it returns a value.

What am I doing wrong? 
I'm expecting a numerical value if its true and and error if its false.

Comment: You forgot to mention the expected output.

Comment: What do you mean it returns a value?

Comment: Put your alternation in a non-capturing group. This way your word boundaries will be in factor for each item.

Comment: You need to group `$list= "/\b($keywords)\b/i";`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat if a word is found i'm expecting a numerical value in the echo. If a word is not found then an error.

Comment: `preg_match` does not throw any exception or error. You will need to manually trigger it. In the meanwhile, you can see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14056831/6099347

Comment: @revo Thanks! that did it. If you write your comment as an answer ill accept it for this post.

Comment: Use join `$keywords = '\b' . join('\b|\b', $keywords ) . '\b';`

Comment: @S.Jovan This was the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Commas in preg\_match string of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692766/commas-in-preg-match-string-of-words)

Comment: This is not a duplicate since there are 2 different issues here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current regex, [`\bl.*ion|test|one|two|three\b`](https://regex101.com/r/8KM0HS/1), the first `\b` only affects the first alternative and the last `\b` only affects the last alternative.

Besides, since you want to only restrict matching of keywords to *a single word*, you cannot rely on `.*` pattern as `.` matches any char but a line break char.

You should use either `\S*` (to match 0+ non-whitespace chars, that also include punctuation) or `\w*` (to match 0+ letters, digits, and `_`).

So, you need to do two things: 1) redefine the `$keywords` array and 2) use a *grouping* construct around the alternatives when `implode`ing to group the alternatives so that the first and last `\b` could be applied to each alternative.

```
$keywords = array(
    "l\w*ion",     // <-- Here, a `\w` is used instead of .
    "test",
    'one',
    'two',
    'three'
);

$list= "/\b(?:" . implode($keywords,"|") . ")\b/i"; // <-- Here, the (?:...) groups alternatives
$my_string= "This is my testing";
if (preg_match($list, $my_string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
  echo $matches[0][1];
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/r7yuTj).

Now, the pattern is `\b(?:l\w*ion|test|one|two|three)\b` and `\b`s apply to all the alternatives. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iNW6b6/2).

Comment: @altoids Why doesn't it? What do you expect? If you only want to match within 1 word, replace `.*` with `\w*`  or even `\S*`. See [`\b(?:l\S*ion|test|one|two|three)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/iNW6b6/1) (or [this one with `\w*`](https://regex101.com/r/iNW6b6/2)).

Comment: The words in my `$keywords` variable should match specific words. With your solution its matching `liar dfsglotion`

Comment: @altoids As I wrote above, replace `l.*ion` with `l\w*ion`, or `l\S*ion`